# Only getting the last in when loop though the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok if i Print out the values inside the loop i will get all the result from  the db but when i try to loop thought the array list in Driver class i'm am only getting the last value of the array.
/**************************studentdata class ******************************/

```
 public ArrayList<Student> AllStudentdata() throws SQLException {
    Student student = null;
    ArrayList<Student> Studentlist = new ArrayList<Student>();
    String Sql = "CALL `studentsdb`.`SelectStudentsGarde`()";
    try {
        stat = con.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (result.next()) {
            student = new Student();
            student.setFristName(result.getString(1));
            student.setLastName(result.getString(2));       
            Studentlist.add(student);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return Studentlist;
}
```

/************************** Driver class ******************************/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<Student> Studentlist=new ArrayList<Student>();

    Studentdata studata = new Studentdata();

    try {
        Studentlist=studata.AllStudentdata();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println(Studentlist.size());


    for(int i = 0;i<Studentlist.size();i++)
    {




        System.out.println(Studentlist.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is Driver class?

Comment: Show us the code where you're printing out the results?

Comment: i just added it's where the Driver class is.

Answer (score 3):

Shot in the dark, I didn't debug this, but you keep resetting the student reference in your loop.  Try this:

```
    while (result.next()) {

        Student student = new Student(); //declare a new student

        student.setFristName(result.getString(1));

        student.setLastName(result.getString(2));       

        Studentlist.add(student);


    }
```

Comment: still only getting the last value

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger??

Comment: found the error it was in my Student class have some of the variable set to static.